# format in ZXing?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am just wondering what is the format in Zxing.

`String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");`

Do you think I can delete this line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string naming the format of the barcode scanned, like "QR_CODE" or "UPC_A". Values come from the class [BarcodeFormat](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.java). Can you remove it? sure, don't write this line of code if you don't need it!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest version in the trunk](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Contents.java):

```
    /**
     * Call intent.getStringExtra(RESULT_FORMAT) to determine which barcode format was found.
     * See Contents.Format for possible values.
     */
    public static final String RESULT_FORMAT = "SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT";
```

`Contents.Format` actually doesn't exist (anymore), but browsing through the code it seems fair to assume the "formats" have been replaced by "types". `Contents.Type` defines the following possibilities:

```
public static final String TEXT = "TEXT_TYPE";
public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL_TYPE";
public static final String PHONE = "PHONE_TYPE";
public static final String SMS = "SMS_TYPE";
public static final String CONTACT = "CONTACT_TYPE";
public static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION_TYPE";
```

In other words: it gives you information about the type of data that is encoded by the scanned barcode. If you don't care about the type, you can simply ignore it.

Comment: Reasonable guess but no that's not it. I'll fix that javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using the intent integrator? If so, this is the kind of barcode that you just scanned. I don't know what your purposes are, but if you want to support more barcodes, you might want to consider this line more important.